# Volume of a specific region

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

Volume of region bounded by $x^2+y^2 \leq 4$, $x \geq 0$, $0<z<x^2-y^2$

I have used the volume formula but not sure of the limits of integration.If I take the limits like the below, I get the answer zero.

$V  = \int \int \int dzdydx$

$V =\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{4-x^2} \int_{0}^{x^2-y^2} dzdydx$

Is the Limit setting correct? Please suggest an easy way to solve this.

Comment: The answer is $\large\color{red}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for unaccepting. I modified the answer and sorry for the error earlier. Take care.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Appreciate it. You too take care @Math Lover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
V & \equiv \bbox[5px,#ffd]{\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 4}\bracks{x \geq 0}
\bracks{0 < z < x^{2} - y^{2}}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z}
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2}
\bracks{\rho\cos\pars{\phi} \geq 0}
\bracks{z < \rho^{2}\cos\pars{2\phi}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\phi}
_{\ds{Cylindrical\ Coordinates}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2}
\bracks{-\cos\pars{\phi} \geq 0}
\bracks{z < \rho^{2}\cos\pars{2\phi}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2}
\bracks{-\cos\pars{\phi} \geq 0}
\bracks{z < \rho^{2}\cos\pars{2\phi}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2}
\bracks{\sin\pars{\phi} \geq 0}
\bracks{z < -\rho^{2}\cos\pars{2\phi}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2}
\bracks{z < -\rho^{2}\cos\pars{2\phi}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2}
\bracks{z < -\rho^{2}\cos\pars{\phi}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2}
\bracks{z < -\rho^{2}\cos\pars{\phi}}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd z\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{z < \rho\sin\pars{\phi}}\,\dd z
\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{4}\rho\sin\pars{\phi}
\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi = \bbx{\large\color{red}{4}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: +1 it is a lot more complicated in cartesian coordinates. My wrong bound on $z$ made everything easier but of course it was not correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

After Felix Marin's prompt, I realized there was a mistake in my upper bound of z which led to wrong result. I had written it only in terms of $y$ which is not true. It is a function of both $x$ and $y$. So the best way to proceed is using cylindrical coordinates.

We have been given below bounds for the region -

i) $x^2 + y^2 \le 4$ or $x \le r \cos \theta, y \le r \sin \theta$ where $r = 2$.

ii) $x \ge 0 \,$ i.e $ \,r \cos\theta \ge 0$ or $\cos \theta \ge 0 \implies (-\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2})$.

iii) $0 \le z \le x^2 - y^2 = r^2(cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta) = r^2 \cos 2\theta $.
As $z \ge 0 \implies$ $\, cos^2\theta \ge sin^2\theta$ or $\, (-\frac{\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4})$ [based on restriction given by (ii)]

Now the integration -

$
\begin{align}
V &= \displaystyle\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \int_0^2 \int_{0}^{r^2 \cos2\theta} dz \, r \,dr \,d\theta \\
\\
&= \displaystyle \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \int_0^2 r^3 \, \cos2\theta \, \,dr \,d\theta \\
\\
&= \displaystyle \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} [\frac {r^4}{4}]_0^2 \, \cos2\theta \, \,d\theta \\
\\
&= \displaystyle 4 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \cos2\theta \, d\theta \\
\\
&= \displaystyle 2 [\sin2\theta]_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} = 4\\
\end{align}
$

Comment: The answer is $\large\color{red}{4}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin I do not see anything wrong with my working but will re-check sometime later.

Comment: I checked it with ${\tt Mathematica}$
$$
\tt \text{Clear}[x,y,z];\int _0^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty }\text{If}\left[x^2+y^2<4\land z<x^2-y^2,1,0\right]dxdydz
$$